# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, aubio

Basic rundown of what I want the program to do:

**Aubio prints the frequency (pitch) and volume (volume) from what's being input from the microphone**

**I want to iterate over the dictionary, and based on which frequency is output, print the color matching which key in the dictionary the frequency from samples is being put out**

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

Would anyone be able to help me? The code in question is the **for** statement

```
import aubio
import numpy as num
import pyaudio
import sys

# Some constants for setting the PyAudio and the
# Aubio.
BUFFER_SIZE = 2048
CHANNELS = 1
FORMAT = pyaudio.paFloat32
METHOD = "default"
SAMPLE_RATE = 44100
HOP_SIZE = BUFFER_SIZE//2
PERIOD_SIZE_IN_FRAME = HOP_SIZE
index = 0

def main(args):

    # Initiating PyAudio object.
    pA = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    # Open the microphone stream.
    mic = pA.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                  rate=SAMPLE_RATE, input=True,
                  frames_per_buffer=PERIOD_SIZE_IN_FRAME)

    # Initiating Aubio's pitch detection object.
    pDetection = aubio.pitch(METHOD, BUFFER_SIZE,
                             HOP_SIZE, SAMPLE_RATE)
    # Set unit.
    pDetection.set_unit("Hz")
    # Frequency under -40 dB will considered
    # as a silence.
    pDetection.set_silence(-40)

    # Infinite loop!
    while True:

        # Always listening to the microphone.
        data = mic.read(PERIOD_SIZE_IN_FRAME)
        # Convert into number that Aubio understand.
        samples = num.fromstring(data,
                                 dtype=aubio.float_type)
        # Finally get the pitch.
        pitch = pDetection(samples)[0]
        # Compute the energy (volume)
        # of the current frame.
        volume = num.sum(samples**2)/len(samples)
        # Format the volume output so it only
        # displays at most six numbers behind 0.
        volume = "{:6f}".format(volume)

        answer = pitch_detection(samples)

        # Finally print the pitch and the volume.
        print(str(pitch) + " " + str(volume) + (str(answer)))


def pitch_detection(samples):
    colordict = {
        (0.0, 13.99): "Red",
        (14.00, 250.00): "Blue",
    }

    for index, key in enumerate(colordict, start=0):
        if samples > colordict[key][0] and samples < colordict[key][1]:
            return key
        return "Not Found"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: For debugging this yourself, it would really help to either run in a debugger, or print things out (like `print(colordict[key][0], colordict[key][1])` so you can see what you're asking Python to do for you instead of just guessing at it. If you do this, you'll see that `colordict[key]` is a string, like `"Red"`, so `colordict[key][0]` is a single character, like `"R"`, and `colordict[key][1]` is the next character, like `"e"`. You can't compare either of those to an array of floats.

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually _wanted_ to compare here. Maybe you wanted `key[0]` and `key[1]`, which are floats, so they can be compared to arrays of floats? But, even then, the result of the comparison is an array of bools, which you can't use in an `if` statement.

Comment: As a wild guess: do you want to get back an array of strings, one per sample, where each is `Red` or `Blue` depending on whether it's in the range 0-13.99 or 14-250? (If so, what are you supposed to use for 13.995, or 252?) To do that, you either need to loop over `samples`, or, better, use vectorized operations instead of an `if` statement.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do, how would I loop over samples?

Answer (score 1):

`samples` is a numpy array.
`colordict[key][0]` is a char (since `colordict[key]` is a text like `"Red"`, the `[0]` will get first char from that string `"R"`)

Your comparision `if samples > colordict[key][0] and samples < colordict[key][1]:` is comparing numpy array with a char and that fails.

Now, I'm not sure what you really want. if you mean `key[0]` and `key[1]` (to get each value from the key separately) then you would need to compare to a single float, not `samples` (which contain multiple values - it is an array) or maybe iterate over `samples` to compare?

Comment: Probably better "string of length 1" (or smth similar) instead of "char" :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for index, key in enumerate(colordict):
    if pitch > key[0] and pitch < key[1]:
        return colordict[key]
```

Ended up fixing it. Thank you all <3